# SwiftUI -pass image data f List -> Detail with scaling animation using matchedGeometryEffect

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

Goal: Pass image data from List -> Detail with scaling zoom in animation similar to Apple Photos App.

What I did: used matched geometry effect, which worked perfectly.

Problem: I can only get this to work hardcoded, as I have both List() and Detail() on the same ContentView(), I cannot figure out how to pass data List-> Detail

Appreciate any inputs!

```
import SwiftUI




struct Grid: View {
    
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List{
           Image("cover")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .padding()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "animation", in: namespace)
            
            Image("cover2")
                 .resizable()
                 .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                 .cornerRadius(4)
                 .padding()
                 .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "animation", in: namespace)
        }

   }
}

struct Detail: View {
    
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        
            Image("cover")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(40)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "animation", in: namespace)
        
      
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.234857142, green: 0.043259345, blue: 0.04711621255, alpha: 1)))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Namespace private var ns
    @State private var showDetails: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            if showDetails {
                Detail(namespace: ns)
            }
            else {
                Grid(namespace: ns)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                showDetails.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper to pass data between views.
For that you need observable object class (e.g. `CoverData`) with published properties.

Also you should use unique id for `matchedGeometryEffect` for views you want to group (e.g. name of the image)

I made minimal changes to your code, see if this is what you looking for:

```
import SwiftUI


class CoverData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var images = ["cover", "cover2"]
    @Published var selected = ""
    @Published var showDetails: Bool = false
}

struct Grid: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coverData: CoverData
    
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(coverData.images.indices) { index in
                let image = coverData.images[index]
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
                    .padding()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: image, in: namespace)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        coverData.selected = image
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            coverData.showDetails.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
   }
}

struct Detail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coverData: CoverData

    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        
            Image(coverData.selected)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(40)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: coverData.selected, in: namespace)
        
      
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.234857142, green: 0.043259345, blue: 0.04711621255, alpha: 1)))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Namespace private var ns
    @StateObject private var coverData = CoverData()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            if coverData.showDetails {
                Detail(namespace: ns)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        coverData.showDetails.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Grid(namespace: ns)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(coverData)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks @kamillo! do you know how to animate also on dismiss?

Comment: @ManeManero, It seems that there is some issue with animating views on ZStack when they have the same (0) index, this could be fixed by setting zIndex for detail view, e.g. `.zIndex(1.0)`